# CSS styling of accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a little problem with setting style of contents of an accordion. Problem is that style defined in a **CSS** file does not get applied to the contents of my **accordion** when I use following code and a separate **CSS** file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var str = '<h3><a href="#">Device</a></h3>' +
            '<div class="content">'+
                '<div class="block left">' +
                    '<img width=30 height=30/>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="block left">' +
                    '<img width=30 height=30/>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '<h3><a href="#">VM</a></h3>' +
            '<div class="content">'+
                '<div class="block left">' +
                    '<img width=30 height=30/>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="block left">' +
                    '<img width=30 height=30/>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>';
```

Related code from the **CSS** file:

```
div.toolbox-block {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
div.left {
    float:left !important;
}
```

Code above works fine if I set the style inline to the tags in the variable str as:

```
str = '<h3><a href="#">Device</a></h3>' +
            '<div class="content">'+
                '<div style="width:30px; height:30px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1); float: left;">' +
                    '<img width=30 height=30/>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div style="width:30px; height:30px; overflow: hidden;  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);float:left;">' +
                    '<img width=30 height=30/>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '<h3><a href="#">VM</a></h3>' +
            '<div class="content">'+
                '<div style="width:30px; height:30px; overflow: hidden;  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);float:left;">' +
                    '<img width=30 height=30/>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div style="width:30px; height:28px; overflow: hidden;  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);float:left;">' +
                    '<img width=30 height=30/>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>';
```

Comment: How do you include your CSS file? Could you add your `<link>` tag and your directory structure?

Comment: I am adding the CSS file correctly as all other styles on the page work just fine.

Comment: div {
    display:block;
} you don't need this, a div is by default a block level element.

Comment: The class names differ. It's `tool-box-block` in your CSS file, but `class="block"` in your HTML.

Comment: @Zeta shoot. That's embarrassing.

Comment: Spelling = accordion. I can't edit ;)

Comment: :P today seems to be some kind of my typo day.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular reason you are including the markup for the accordion in this way? Instead of `append`ing it via a variable, how about you add it to your HTML file, hide it with CSS initially, and then make it visible using jQuery on document ready.

Like so:

```
<div id="accordion" class="hidden">
    <h3><a href="#">Device</a></h3>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="block left">
            <img width=30 height=30/>
        </div>
        <div class="block left">
            <img width=30 height=30/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">VM</a></h3>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="block left">
            <img width=30 height=30/>
        </div>
        <div class="block left">
            <img width=30 height=30/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#accordion').removeClass('hidden') // removes default CSS class to make it visible
        .accordion(); // makes it an accordion
});
</script>
```

That way, the markup for the accordion is not being generated by javascript and, if I'm not terribly mistaken, that should apply your CSS rules just fine.

Comment: No particular reason. The str given above in code is just an example. Actually this variable is populated dynamically based on some other operations in a loop. Earlier I was using append each time i need to add some new content to the accordion but I thought to construct a string markup for accordion and then call append just once.